# Migrate sqlite database to mysql database in itdb asset management tool

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, migrate

I have downloaded ITDB -  IT ITems DataBase application from http://www.sivann.gr/software/itdb.

SQLite database is using in this application. Now I want to migrate this to MySQL database. I have migrated the `.db` file to `.sql` file also import the database to MySQL database. Now how to connect it in this existing project any idea?

Comment: Can you share some more information, such as: what have you tried so far, has the documentation not helped?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have fixed the issue by using the following line instead of including .db file in init.php file   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=itdb', 'root', 'root', array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

Comment: @Srim Please post your question as an answer and accept it so others can find the solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using the following line instead of including .db file in init.php file $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=itdb', 'root', 'root', array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));